# I have created a form where i can upload image but i have problem.while displaying it . I jave written the codes below

Tags: php, mysql, file

if(isset($_POST['submit'])

{

if(!file_exists("Uploads"))

{

makdir("Uploads/");

}

$base=basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

$file_path="Uploads/".$base;

if(file_exists($file_path))

{

$err[]="File already exist";

$uploadOk=0;

}

else

{

$uploadOk=1;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);

}

if($uploadOk ==1)

{

?>

" height="100" width="100">

}

}

Comment: Sorry, but in my code there is if not If. I made mistake while typing

Comment: Parameter should be $_FILES['image']['name']. I tried to edit my query but i couldn't so sorry for doing mistake while typing

Comment: I have copied and paste my code . Can u see my codes ?

Comment: Cid I have upload the whole code here ..can u check where is the mistake here?   <img src="<?php echo ".$file_path.";?>" height='100' width='100'>

Comment: `makdir` doesn't exist

Comment: Do u want to say that mkdir function doean't exist in php ?

Comment: Nope, I want to say that function mAkdir doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh yeah...that was aslo my typing mistake. Because i tried to copy paste but whole codes doesnt appear thas why i write it from the keyboard

Comment: Just copy/paste your code, select it, then click the code button `{}`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) can help you formatting

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the directory where you are uploading the image and confirm its same directory from where you are trying to fetch image.
2. It look like that you have given incorrect image path for loading image try to debug it with pressing F12 in your browser (chrome) if it is showing error in console tab than the path you are giving is incorrect.